# Is making something "atomic" essentially just a lock mechanism?

Tags: parallel-processing, theory, atomic

From the OpenMP summary pdf: "operation ensures that a specific storage location is updated atomically". This brough up the question for me what "atomic" is and wheter it is just a lock mechanism. So if I remember correctly "atomic" means that some hardware support is built in to prevent anything else from changing the value. So is making something "atomic" essentially just implementing a lock mechanism or is it something more?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be some confusion around "atomicity" vs "isolation". They're similar concepts, but there is a subtle difference between them. Atomicity means that an operation either completes entirely, or not at all. Isolation guarantees that operations that happen concurrently result in a state that could have been caused by them executing serially.

For example, if the operation is "add 1 to x, then multiply x by 2", and x starts as 3, the result will be 3 if there is any sort of failure, or 8 if there is not. Even if the power cuts out right after 1 is added, the result when you reboot is guaranteed to be 3.

Now consider what happens if this operation is performed twice, concurrently. Both could fail, resulting in x=3. One could fail, x=8. Both could succeed, x=18. If we are guaranteed isolation, these are the only outcomes. But, if we are only given atomicity, not isolation, a fourth outcome could happen, wherein the individual parts are interleaved as "add 1, add 1, multiply by 2, multiply by 2", resulting in x=20!

If you're guaranteed only isolation, but not atomicity, you could end up with x=3, 4, 5, 8, 10, or 18.

With all that said, this is a common misconception, and often when people say "atomicity" they mean both. That's my suspicion of what they mean in the OpenMP documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a value stored in memory is a three-step process.  First the value is fetched from memory and brought to one of the CPU's registers.  Then, the value in the register is changed in some way (say incremented).  Finally, the new value is written back to memory so that it can be used again.

Doing this (or any other) operation atomically simply means that all three of those steps happen, or none of them does.

It only becomes interesting or important when you have another thread or process that also needs to use that same memory value.  Suppose both want to increment the value, which is initially zero.  Without atomic operations, the second thread might read the original value (0) from memory even as the first thread is incrementing it in a register.  Effectively both threads may see the value 0, increment it to 1, and return it to memory.  At the end of this sequence, the value in memory would be 1 despite having been incremented twice.

With an atomic increment operation, there is no way that that sequence can occur.  Once the first thread enters the atomic sequence, there is no way the second thread can read the value in memory before the first thread has incremented it and written it back to memory.  You'll always get the correct value (2).

So, to answer your question, it's *almost* like a lock mechanism.  In particular, it's like a lock mechanism exists around whatever the original operation was.  Atomic operations themselves are frequently used in the implementation of other locking mechanisms, such as mutexes and semaphores.